# Is there a solution to this puzzle in Clive Ke's "How to improve in chess" book?

Tags: analysis, puzzles

I am wondering if there's a solution to this puzzle anywhere.

```
[FEN "3r4/p4k2/1p2bb1p/2p2pp1/5P2/1NP1B2P/PP4P1/4R1K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Here's the description of the puzzle in Clive Ke's "How to improve in chess" book.

"Advance your pawns on one side to gain space on that side so that your pieces have more mobility and more options and your opponent's pieces have less mobility".

Stockfish claims that Black has a significant advantage here. I don't want to see what exactly it would suggest doing, I'm just curious if there's any possible solution at all with such an imbalance.

Comment: What is the puzzle, exactly? Find the best move for White? Find the best move for Black? Whose move is it, anyway?

Comment: This is the legendary game Englisch-Steinitz, demonstrating the advantage of the bishop pair. It's featured in about any book on positional play, or just google it :-)